# How to safely deal with an array pointer when throwing an exception

Tags: c++, exception

When trying to encapsulate C API in C++ method, i found a problem in throwing an exception:

```
int status;
char* log = nullptr;
int infoLogLength;

getFooStatus(&status);
getFooLogLength(&infoLogLength);

if (!status) {
  log = new char[infoLogLength];
  getFooLog(infoLogLength, log);
  throw std::runtime_error(log);
}
```

I am not allowed to modify the interface methods in any way.

From what i understand, i am required to reserve memory for the method to fill, and operate on that. However, throwing the exception will return from the method, not letting me to free the resources. Is my code correct, or should i go around this in some other way?

Comment: if this is c++, why aren't you using strings?

Comment: @RedAlert as i mentioned, i am forced to by the C api - i tried using string internal storage as char array, but to no avail. I might be missing something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std:runtime_error` expects a `std::string`, so give it a `std::string` instead of a `char*`:

```
int status;
getFooStatus(&status);

if (!status) {
    int infoLogLength;
    getFooLogLength(&infoLogLength);
    std::string log(infoLogLength, '\0');
    getFooLog(infoLogLength, &log[0]);
    throw std::runtime_error(log);
}
```

Alternatively, you can pass a `char*`, simply allocate it in a way that promoted auto-freeing, eg:

```
int status;
getFooStatus(&status);

if (!status) {
    int infoLogLength;
    getFooLogLength(&infoLogLength);
    std::vector<char> log(infoLogLength);
    getFooLog(infoLogLength, &log[0]);
    throw std::runtime_error(&log[0]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. As for the first method, i am getting the const char* - char* mismatch. Can I use `&log[0]` instead of `log.data()` ?

Comment: Yes you can use `&log[0]` instead.

Comment: @user3483094: Yes. That's formalized since C++11. In C++03 you formally couldn't rely on it yet, but it still worked on all implementations.

Comment: Also, minor nitpick: std::string does not seem to accept int as constructor parameter. `.reserve()` works though.

Comment: @user3483094: actually, it does accept an int in the constructor, but I forgot that there is another parameter that goes with it. I updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know runtime_error has two overloads, one with a const *char and another as const string&.

I believe constructing a std::string as a local variable and passing that to runtime_error should result in it being cleaned up properly.

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple way to deal with exceptions, without having to refactor the code so that the array is managed by an object whose destructor cleans it up. Namely:

```
char* log = nullptr;

try {
  int status;
  int infoLogLength;

  getFooStatus(&status);
  getFooLogLength(&infoLogLength);

  if (!status) {
    log = new char[infoLogLength];
    getFooLog(infoLogLength, log);
    throw std::runtime_error(log);
  }
} catch (...) {  // special C++ syntax: "catch any exception"
  delete [] log;
  throw; // special C++ syntax: "re-throw" current exception
}
```

If all you have is a single `catch (...)`, it looks a lot as if C++ supports `finally`. The difference betwen `catch (...)` and a `finally` feature is that `catch (...)` does not execute unconditionally: it only executes if there isn't a more specific `catch`. So, if you were to add additional catch clauses in the same `try` block, they would all have to repeat the `delete [] log` clean-up action.

This could be mitigated by using nesting:

```
try {    // real exception-handling try
  try {   // try for unwind protection only
    ...
  } catch (...) {
    // clean-up statements
    throw;
  }
} catch (actual_error &err) {
  ...
} catch (another_exc_type &exc) {
  ...
}
```